# Forked allegro unit tests crash when run

Tags: c, unit-testing, fork, xorg, allegro5

I'm using a custom unit-testing system for c which forks each test into a new process so that if one crashes the others can still be executed uninterrupted. Right now I am trying to use this for testing code that uses Allegro. When I run `al_init()` in `main` (shown below), my testing program terminates after the first test with the error message:

```
X connection to :1 broken (explicit kill or server shutdown).
X connection to :1 broken (explicit kill or server shutdown).
make: *** [Makefile:39: tests/results/collision.result] Error 1
```

Erroneous code causing problems:

```
void MakeCollisionCircleInWorldTest()
{
    Testing_Unimplemented();
}

/*
 * other unimplemented tests here, cropped for brevity
 */ 

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    al_init();
    Testing_Init(argc, argv);

    TESTING_RUN(MakeCollisionCircleInWorldTest);
    TESTING_RUN(DuplicateCollisionCircleTest);
    TESTING_RUN(AddCollisionCircleTest);
    TESTING_RUN(RemoveCollisionCircleTest);
    TESTING_RUN(MoveTest);
    TESTING_RUN(CheckCollisionsTest);

    return 0;
}
```

note: it is `TESTING_RUN` which performs the aforementioned forking. I assume this is related to the crash (perhaps the connection is killed after the first child terminates?), but I'm not certain exactly how, nor how to solve.

When I instead put the call to `al_init()` in each test separately (shown below), there is no premature termination nor error message, but it seems somewhat slow (not unbearably slow, but there is a noticeable pause which shouldn't really be there for tests that just immediately fail because they're unimplemented). Also, it just seems like a bit of a pain to reinit Allegro for every separate test.

```
void MakeCollisionCircleInWorldTest()
{
    al_init();
    Testing_Unimplemented();
}

/*
 * other unimplemented tests here, cropped for brevity
 */ 

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Testing_Init(argc, argv);

    TESTING_RUN(MakeCollisionCircleInWorldTest);
    TESTING_RUN(DuplicateCollisionCircleTest);
    TESTING_RUN(AddCollisionCircleTest);
    TESTING_RUN(RemoveCollisionCircleTest);
    TESTING_RUN(MoveTest);
    TESTING_RUN(CheckCollisionsTest);

    return 0;
}
```

What is causing the crash? Is there some way to initialize Allegro in `main` without breaking my tests?

Comment: You need to scrutinize what the Allegro documentation says about forking processes and whether the child, the parent or both can continue to use resources.  That will control whether you have to reinitialize in each forked test.  The evidence you have so far suggests that your tests do need to establish their own Allegro environment rather than trying to continue to use the parent process's copy of the Allegro environment.  I know nothing about Allegro, so I can't help much more, but making each child do the setup, test and tear-down seems likely to work — and not doing seems not to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem was caused by `al_init()` setting `al_uninstall_system` as an `atexit` function. The result was that the child performed the system uninstall when it exited. This can be prevented by calling `al_install_system(ALLEGRO_VERSION_INT, NULL)` instead of `al_init()`, and then manually calling `al_uninstall_system()` when the parent process finishes. There are other solutions, but that's what I've gone with for now, since my unit test programs only have one exit point.